# Clickable matrix image with python and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to generate a HTML clickable matrix image with matplotlib using imshow. 
My problem is that I basically don't know where the matrix elements will turn out in the plot...?
I want to use the image with the html map tag.
Cheers,
EL

Here's my solution - the adjustment required to the bar solution that tcaswell provided is that ticks and the origin (0,0) have a offset by pixelWidth / 2 and pixelHeight / 2. Positions must be adjusted accordingly

```
def getTransformedCoordinates(f,x,y,imageDPI):
from math import ceil

dpi = f.figure.get_dpi()
height = f.figure.get_figheight()
width = f.figure.get_figwidth()

scale = pngdpi / float(imageDPI)

imageWidth  = width  * imageDPI 
imageHeight = height * imageDPI 
axes = f.axes

data = axes.transData.transform([x,y])

return data[0] * scale, data[1] * scale


def getSquareWidthAndHeight(f,imageDPI):

x1,y1 = getTransformedCoordinates(f,0,0,imageDPI)
x2,y2 = getTransformedCoordinates(f,1,1,imageDPI)

width = abs(x2 - x1)
height = abs(y2 - y1)

return width,height
```

Comment: look in to transforms which will allow you to map between data-space and screen-space.

Comment: I am not a huge fan of my newly given super power, but I think that question is the answer you want.

Comment: The second answer there helped so far. Thanks! :)

Comment: You should up-vote which ever answer helped you